# Button specified in vm's has overflowing text

Tags: html, css

I have a button that has a size specified in vm's. The text inside also has a font size specified in vm's. When the button becomes smaller than a given size the text overflows out of the container and below the button. How can I fix this? (I do plan to use a media query so the button can't become ridiculously small, but this won't fix the issue when the button is of a medium size).

My html is as follows:

```
<div class="socialMediaBtn" id="githubBtn">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i> Github </a>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.socialMediaBtn {
    font-size: 1.25vw;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 2.75vw;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #003333;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.socialMediaBtn > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #003333;
    height: 2.75vw;
    width: 15vw;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.socialMediaBtn > a:hover {
    background-color: #669999;
    color: white;
}
```

I also have a link tag at the top of the page that imports font-awesome.min.css.

Here is a jsFiddle, try resizing the window to see the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/1pwyn5ko/. (On my webpage the text of the button is actually visible below the button rather than just disappearing, unless I give the div the overflow: hidden css property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dynamic height (`height: 2.75vw;`), but you have a fixed line-height (`line-height: 50px;`).

Just put your line-height with the same dynamic height, and you're good to go !

```
.socialMediaBtn {
    font-size: 1.25vw;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 2.75vw;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2.75vw;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #003333;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1pwyn5ko/1/